# Site blocker chrome extension (check description)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am creating a chrome extension which will block youtube , and ott platforms like Amazon Prime Netflix
Until a certain task is not completed
[If the task is not completed and if I try to open youtube.com it will show a message task is not completed - and it will redirect you to the website where we can complete the task ]

***How do I make this work for multiple sites like primevideo.com , netflix.com etc.***

I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
function isPrimeVideoURL(url) {
    var reg =  new RegExp(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?primevideo.com\/.*/)
    return url.match(reg);
}
```

**Main working code**

```
function isAccessingYoutube(changeInfo, tab) {
    // from other page to youtube
    if (changeInfo.status == 'loading' && changeInfo.url && isYoutubeURL(changeInfo.url)) {
        return true;
    }
    // refresh in youtube
    else if (changeInfo.status == 'loading' && isYoutubeURL(tab.url)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function isYoutubeURL(url) {
    var reg =  new RegExp(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?youtube.com\/.*/)
    return url.match(reg);
}


function isTimeOver(lastAcceptedDatetime, hourUnit) {
    if (lastAcceptedDatetime) {
        var lastAcceptedDate = new Date(lastAcceptedDatetime);
        var now = new Date();
        var diff = now - lastAcceptedDate;
        var diffInHours = Math.floor(diff / 3.6e6);
        console.log("diff :", diff, "diffInHours :", diffInHours, "hourUnit :", hourUnit);
        if (diffInHours < hourUnit) {
            return false; // can watch youtube
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function isexamplesiteSubmissionURL(url) {
    var reg =  new RegExp(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?examplesite.com\/problems\/.*\/submissions\/?/)
    return url.match(reg);
}

function checkSubmissionTable(tabId) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {message: 'check-submission-table'});
    }, 2000);
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
    function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        if (isAccessingYoutube(changeInfo, tab)) { // 1. if user access youtube
            chrome.storage.sync.get({
                features: {
                    autoRedirection: {
                        enabled: true,
                        hourUnit: 12
                    }
                },
                lastAcceptedDatetime: null
            }, function(option) {
                if (option.features.autoRedirection.enabled) { // 2. If nlny is enabled
                    if (isTimeOver(option.lastAcceptedDatetime, option.features.autoRedirection.hourUnit)) { // 3. If timeover
                        // red icon & redirect
                        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:'assets/icons/red_48.png'});
                        chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {url: chrome.extension.getURL('redirect_to_examplesite.html')});
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && isexamplesiteSubmissionURL(tab.url)) {
            checkSubmissionTable(tabId);
        }
    }
);

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.message === 'mission-clear') {
            chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:'assets/icons/blue_48.png'});
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: It would be great if someone could help me out here. What functions need to be added or editing the code based on one custom website like (Netflix)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add the sites you want this to work with to your `content_scripts` section in your `manifest.json`? `  `"content_scripts": [{ "matches": [ "*://youtube.com/*", "*://netflix.com/*" ]}` etc.

Comment: @Andy I have the examplesite in manifest.json content_scripts (I dont think I can add the site here)
`"content_scripts":[
      {
        "matches": ["*://*.examplesite.com/problems/*"],
        "js":[
 ` Could you help me in editing the current file I dont think it is very tricky I think I just need to create a function for each website